# Multitouch touchEvents not triggered as they should on Safari Mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, safari, touch-event

I have various touchEvents detection on a page on Safari Mobile (a controller, if you want to know...). They all work well indepedantly, but whenever I have a first touchpoint pressed, If I touch a new point, the events are triggered when I trigger a new one.

For example :

- I hold the stick with a finger. It's not moving
- I press a button, a touchStart event should be triggered but is not
- If I move the stick, the touchStart event is triggered
- If I let go of the button, the touchStart is triggered, but not the touchEnd
- If I move the stick (touchMove), the touchEnd is triggered

You understand how in my case it's a problem. I get buttons triggered with delay, or getting stuck until I move the stick, etc...

Is there a workaround ? thanks

Comment: If you post some example code it would be easier for us to look into

Comment: Seems like someone else is running into this problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314185/multiple-touches-touchend-event-fired-only-when-a-touchmove-occurs

Comment: The problem was finally fixed in iOS6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314185/multiple-touches-touchend-event-fired-only-when-a-touchmove-occurs/12992353#12992353